# Crontab executes shell script: Mount error(13): Permission denied

Tags: linux, shell, cron, mount, permission-denied

I have got a RasPi and I actually try to execute a shellscript to automount a folder at every Reboot.
Script Command is:
sudo mount -t cifs 'folderpath' 'pointtomount' -o username=xxx,password=xxx,sec=ntlm

It works perfect if I use it manually but via cronjob it responses "Mount Error(13): Permission denied" and the mount can't be executed.
Means cronjob executes the file at least.

My idea was to mount it manually and check if automount is disabled in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab. As it's just a folder I only found it in mtab.
I can't write in it but nowhere's "noauto" in the options so probabbly everything is correct.

Not certain if it has sth. in common with crontab execute rights but ls -lha /usr/bin/crontab output is -rwxr-sr-x 1.

If anyone of you got any clues how to solve this problem, i'd appreciate help.
Thanks

EDIT1:

Okay after hours and hours it seems to be working in /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart.sh (type "sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart.sh"). In that file I wrote "@/home/pi/scripttoexecute.sh". In my executescript I wrote "sudo mount -t cifs 'foldertomount' 'directorypath' -o credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm". Obviously to use the smbcredentials file, write "sudo nano /root/.smbcredentials" and in there "username=xxx" and next line "password=xxx" and optional domain.
Thanks to all and I hope that this might save someone elses time.
Not sure if it has sth in common with apt-get upgrade and apt-get update before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple things here, first off every user can have their own crontab.  For example:

```
crontab -e # Edit crontab of current user
crontab -u root -e # Edit crontab of root user (might need sudo for this)
crontab -u www-data -e # Edit crontab of www-data user
```

Another thing is that if you don't use `crontab -e` to edit the file, and actually edit the `/etc/crontab` file directly (do something like `vim /etc/crontab`), you can actually specify the user you'd like to run the cron as:

```
* * * * * root mount -t cifs /path/to/folder /point/to/mount -o username=xxx,password=xxx,sec=ntlm
```

Comment: Thanks in advance already. 
I was using crontab -e for the actual user and also wrote it into sudo crontab -e what should be the same as crontab -u root -e, isn't it?
I'll try your ideas tho and keep you up to date.

Atm it is strange anyways, sometimes it's already mounted at startup and sometimes it mounts it as i want (cronlog notifications) and sometimes i get permissions denied, that's kinda strange..

Comment: Yes, `sudo crontab -e` should be the same as `crontab -u root -e`, although for the latter you may need to use `sudo`.  

Btw though, I reread your question, and I was wondering why this needs to be a cron?  If you want this to run at reboot, you may want to put the command in a script that runs on reboots rather than have it on a cron.  Perhaps a file like `rc.local`.  Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, or how rasberry pi's work, but you may find [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md) useful.

Comment: Okay finally it works.. No idea why it didnt work instantly but after all the rc.local file was the right thing.
For everyone with the same problem:
"sudo nano /etc/rc.local" and there 
"/bin/mount -t cifs 'foldertomount' 'mountpoint' -o username=xxx,password=xxx,sec=ntlm"

Im still confused why it didnt work at first but thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Nevermind don't get what this system does.
I set my command as comment in rc.local -> didn't mount it. Setting it back to rc.local it worked again, afterwards i checked my LXDE-pi/autostart file and realized my start script with the command gets executed as well and wanted to test if it has sth in common with the mount. Setting it as comment but keeping rc.local active -> no mount anymore.
I don't get it, if anyone has an idea why it is like that, you are welcome.
Otherwise, whatever idc as long it works lol.

Comment: @LinkM That's the software spirit!  It's either "My code doesn't work, and I don't know why!" or "My code **does** work, and I don't know why!"

Comment: I don't like both cases haha but you're right my friend.

Answer (score 1):

To run via root's crontab at reboot, type:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add this line:

```
@reboot mount -t cifs 'folderpath' 'pointtomount' -o username=xxx,password=xxx,sec=ntlm
```

But really, shouldn't you be [adding your auto-mounts to `/etc/fstab`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103541/automount-cifs-shares-on-boot)?

Comment: I exactly did this ... No idea why but it didnt work.
Tried to mount it through rc.local, but it bugged, and didnt get how i can write in fstab. From one day to the other somehow it works every time. Definetly not through crontab cause I disabled the script and it still gets mounted.
No idea how it gets mounted now but it works...
Thanks for the suggestion and the tutorial, gonna try it tho to keep sure  it gets mounted every time.